# Specified cast is not valid in C# and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

How can I fix this ? I try to stop duplication in my attendance but I can't solve this. I try to cast from date.

```
            if(label1.Text != "" && label2.Text != "" && label3.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                string c = @"(select count(*)from Attendance where Date='"+label1.Text+"')";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Attendance (Name,Date,empIn)VALUES(@Name,@Date,@empIn)", con);              
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmdc = new MySqlCommand(c,con);
                int count = (int)cmdc.ExecuteScalar();
                if(count > 0)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("This data is already IN");
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label3.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label1.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@empIn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label2.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Attendance Inserted");
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }


        }
```

Comment: i try to cast him from date

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label1.Text;` => why you're storing date as `varchar`? What is the data type of `Date` column?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto varchar mr tetsuya

Comment: Just an advice: Better to store date values as `date` or `datetime` rather than `varchar`, because it's easier to convert into C# `DateTime` struct. The invalid cast may occur because the command tried to convert string into date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [insert ignore](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/) *MySql syntax*. Be careful with sql *parameters*: if query wants `DateTime` (`@Date` parameter), provide `DateTime` (`DateTime.ParseExact` and alike):

```
string sql = 
  @"insert ignore Attendance(
      Name,
      Date,
      empIn)
    values(
     @Name,
     @Date,
     @empIn)";

//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con)) {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label3.Text;
  // If Date is DateTime, provide DateTime, not string
  //TODO: provide the right date time format here
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(label1.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@empIn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label2.Text;

  if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Attendance Inserted");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("This data is already IN");
}
```

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko the error is System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: @Hei Sciff: you should put the *right format* (see `//TODO:` comment). In the code provided, I've assumed that the format is `"d/M/yyyy"`, e.g. `14/1/2019`. If you use different `DateTime` representation you should change the format.

Comment: @Hei Sciff: According to wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_Philippines), you cay use *Month-Day-Year* format, if it's your case the format is `"M-d-yyyy"`